# how can i add many tailwind classes at once in some common class so that i dont have to use long class names everytime

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am working with tailwind CSS.
I don't know react or next.js.

I want to give each anchor tag five-six tailwind classes, but i dont want to write all anchor tag then add classes manually,

what I want is to give them a common class name, like `class="link"` then in `style.css`, I will add all tailwind classes to `link` class.

its not working, but is there any way

`home.html`

```
<!-- Old -->

<div>
    <a href="" class="duration-500 hover:scale-110 hover:bg-slate-100 p-2 rounded-lg">A</a>
    <a href="" class="duration-500 hover:scale-110 hover:bg-slate-100 p-2 rounded-lg">B</a>
    <a href="" class="duration-500 hover:scale-110 hover:bg-slate-100 p-2 rounded-lg">C</a>
    <a href="" class="duration-500 hover:scale-110 hover:bg-slate-100 p-2 rounded-lg">D</a>
    <a href="" class="duration-500 hover:scale-110 hover:bg-slate-100 p-2 rounded-lg">E</a>
</div>

<!-- New -->
<div>
    <a href="" class="link">A</a>
    <a href="" class="link">B</a>
    <a href="" class="link">C</a>
    <a href="" class="link">D</a>
    <a href="" class="link">E</a>
</div>
```

`style.css`

```
.link{
    /* all tailwind classes */
    duration-500 hover:scale-110 hover:bg-slate-100 p-2 rounded-lg
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@apply` to inline any existing utility classes into your own custom CSS.

This is useful when you need to write custom CSS like you want in your case.

You should be able to use `@apply` directive like this:

```css
.link{
    @apply duration-500 hover:scale-110 hover:bg-slate-100 p-2 rounded-lg;
}
```

You can read more about it here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply